# Grails / Spring Boot application shutting down with no error reported in log

Tags: java, spring, grails, spring-boot

I have a Grails 3 application using Spring boot and creating a runnable JAR file with embedded Tomcat.

The application runs ok for a while but a few times every day the process just completely quits without even writing an error to the application's log file.

Are there known causes for this?

Comment: Are you running the application on Linux?

Comment: Do you see any `hs_err_pid<pid>.log` files in directory, where you start your app?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson - yes on Linux

Comment: @RandallFlagg don't see any hs_err_pid files

Comment: Assuming JVM crashes, this file should be created probably in application directory, but to be on safe side, can you run java with this param:
`java -XX:ErrorFile=targetDir/hs_err_pid_%p.log yourapp.jar` and set targetDir to some predictable location?

Comment: @GregPagendam-Turner In that case, I'd guess that it's Linux's out of memory killer that's killing your app.